# Twitter Bootstrap tooltips break on page change because of $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Since jQuery $(document).ready only fires once. My Twitter bootstrap tooltips break on changing of pages.

I currently use something simple like below to initialize my tooltips:

```
$(function () {
// for tooltips
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
  });
});
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```